# Laravel 5.3 middleware execution order bug

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

I'm having a problem:

No matter what I do, the **auth** middleware is ALWAYS executed before other middlewares!

Here's what I tried:
Created a middleware named **aa** (so it comes before **auth** at least alphabetically).

I also put it before the **auth** one in `Kernel.php`

Then I created a nested route group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'test', 'middleware' => 'aa'], function() {
  Route::get('/', function() {
    return 'test';
  });

  Route::group(['prefix' => 'test2', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {
      return 'test2';
    });
  });
});
```

If I go to `/test/test2` the **auth** middleware gets executed before the **aa** one.

If I go to `/test` then I see the **aa** middleware is executed..

the middleware code is really easy:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  dd('aa middleware!');
}
```

Here is Kernel.php as requested from @Rimon Khan

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
  protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
  ];

  protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
      \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
      \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
      \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
      \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
      \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
      \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
      'bindings',
    ],
  ];

  protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'aa' => \App\Http\Middleware\Aa::class,
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class
  ];
}
```

Edit: @prateekkathal  you will never convert me to use spaces instead of tabs even if you force edit my post and change the indentation! lol

Comment: what you want to do? provide more details.

Comment: I want  a middleware of my choice to be executed BEFORE the auth one

Comment: provide your kernel.php file

Comment: @nonsensei Did you find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. You should override the $middlewarePriority in your Kernel.php.

```
/**
 * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
 *
 * Forces the listed middleware to always be in the given order.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
];
```